# Showing the image of the preimage of a set is the set itself

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Question:
>
> Let $f:( X,d )\rightarrow ( Y,e )$ be a map between metric spaces, let $U \subseteq X$ and$ V\subseteq Y$.
>
> Show that $V=f\left ( f^{-1}\left ( V \right ) \right )$.

Recall by definition the pre-image of a set V:

$$f^{-1} ( V  )=\{ x \in X  \mid f ( x  ) \in V \}$$

If it helps:
$f\left ( x \right )=x^{2}$

$$f^{-1}(\{x\})=
\left\{\begin{matrix}
\sqrt x, -\sqrt x  &x>0 \\ 
0 & x=0\\
\emptyset  & x<0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems weird that $U$ never gets used in your question. Are you sure that you typed it correctly?

Answer (score 3):

The statement is false in general (more specifically, whenever $f$ is not surjective).

For example, if $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined by $f(x)=x^2$, and $V$ is the set $(-\infty,0)$ of negative real numbers, then
$$f^{-1}(V)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:f(x)\in V\}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x^2<0\}=\varnothing$$
and therefore $f(f^{-1}(V))=\varnothing$, which is not $V$.

Comment: Strictly speaking, we don't need $f$ to be surjective, we just need $V\subset f(X)$.

Comment: @florence: I see what you mean, though it just depends on whether you want to impose a condition on $f$ for the statement to be true for arbitrary $V$, or whether you want to impose a condition on $V$ for the statement to be true for a specific $f$.