# Does $f(A) \cap f(f^{-1}(B))$ equal $f(A) \cap B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

More precisely, for a function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and sets $A \subseteq X$, $B \subseteq Y$, does $f(A) \cap f(f^{-1}(B)) = f(A) \cap B$ even though $f(f^{-1}(B)) \subseteq B$ ?

**Editing to add my thoughts and some context (thanks for the feedback):** after going through [this list of basic properties of images and preimages](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359693/overview-of-basic-results-about-images-and-preimages) as well as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1892671/showing-the-image-of-the-preimage-of-a-set-is-the-set-itself), I believe the statement to be true since $f(A) \cap f(f^{-1}(B)) = f(A \cap f^{-1}(B))$, so the intersection in question is an image which may solve the issues that come with invalidly claiming $f(A) \cap f(f^{-1}(B)) = f(A) \cap B$ since $f(f^{-1}(B)) = B$. However, I don't see how to use this fact to rigorously prove the claim.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Please edit you post to include some of your thoughts.

Comment: Yes. Because we have $f(f^{-1}(B))=B \cap f(X)$ and $f(A) \subseteq f(X)$.

Comment: Apologies! I edited my post with additional thoughts.